# Integration of Cahn-Hilliard-Oono equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, divergence-theorem

I am currently reading a paper on the Cahn-Hilliard-Oono equation with Neumann boundary conditions:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \epsilon u &+ \Delta^2 u - \Delta f(u) = 0, \quad \epsilon \geq 0,\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} &= \frac{\partial \Delta u}{\partial n} = 0 \quad \text{on } \Gamma,\\
&u\lvert_{t=0} = u_0
\end{align}

where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded and regular with boundary $\Gamma$. $n$ denotes the unit outer normal to $\Gamma$ and $f(u) = u^3-u$.

Now the author claims that, when integrating the Cahn-Hilliard-Oono equation over $\Omega$, we receive:

\begin{align}
\frac{d \langle u \rangle}{dt} + \epsilon \langle u \rangle = 0,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\langle \cdot \rangle = \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(\Omega)} \int_{\Omega} \cdot \, dx.
\end{align}

I am feeling really stupid at the moment, because I cannot comprehend whats happening here. Where does the term $\frac{1} {\text{Vol}({\Omega})}$ come from to begin with?

I would have computed:
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \epsilon u &+ \Delta^2 u - \Delta f(u) \, dx = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Omega} u \, dx + \epsilon \int_{\Omega} u \,dx  
\end{align}

Aditionally, I am wondering why the last to terms in the above equation are equal to zero. I tried to justify this with the divergence theorem, but I absolutely messed up:

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \Delta^2 u \,dx = \int_{\Omega} \text{div}(\nabla(\Delta u)) \,dx = \int_{\Gamma} \nabla(\Delta u)\cdot n \, d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega} \nabla 1 \cdot \nabla (\Delta u) dx = 0\\
\int_{\Omega} \Delta f(u) \,dx =\int_{\Omega} \text{div}(\nabla(f(u)) \, dx = \int_{\Gamma} \nabla f(u) \cdot n \, d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega} \nabla 1\cdot \nabla f(u) \, dx = \int_{\Gamma} f'(u) \nabla u \cdot n \, d\Gamma 
\end{align}

Can someone help me out?

Comment: $\langle \cdot \rangle$ just denotes the spatial average of a function and so you need to divide by the length/area/volume when in $1$/$2$/$n$ dimensions respectively. And computing the averaged expressions as you did is exactly what to do; for example, you have $$\int_{\Omega} (\Delta^{2} u) \ dx = \int_{\Gamma} \underbrace{(\nabla \Delta u \cdot n)}_{= \ \partial_{n} \Delta u} \ d \Gamma - \int_{\Omega} \underbrace{(\nabla 1)}_{= \ 0} \cdot (\nabla \Delta u) \ dx = 0$$ Keep going with the other expression.

Comment: @MatthewCassell, thanks for your answer. So did I understood you correctly: Integrating over $\Omega$ leads to $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Omega} u \,dx + \epsilon \int_{\Omega} u \,dx$ and afterwards, I have to divide by volume to obtain the spatial average. Or ist the spatial average something that is directly linked to the integration?

Comment: @MatthewCassell, and concerning the last expression. I am stuck at the term $\int_{\Gamma} ( f'(u) \nabla u) \cdot n \, d\Gamma$, since I know nothing about $\nabla u$.

Comment: No, when you take the average of the equation _by definition of the average_ you are computing $(\text{vol} \Omega)^{-1} \int_{\Omega} (\cdot)$, not just the integral component, though the result comes out the same if you integrate the entire expression and then multiply everything by $(\text{vol} \Omega)^{-1}$. Then by linearity of the integral, you have $$\langle u_{t} + \epsilon u + \dots \rangle = \langle u_{t} \rangle + \epsilon \langle u \rangle + \dots$$ For the second question $$(f'(u) \nabla u) \cdot n = f'(u) (\nabla u \cdot n) = f'(u) \partial_{n} u$$

Comment: @MatthewCassell, okay then I just didn't get that the author was computing the mean of the function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear it makes sense now. May I suggest that you answer your own question and accept it? That way anyone who has a similar question in the future can find the answer and also so that the question is closed and the system won't flag it in the future as requiring an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, not only the integral but the spatial average of the Cahn-Hilliard-Oono equation is computed. Using the divergence theorem, the spatial average of the last two terms computes as follows

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\Delta^2 u \, dx &= \int_{\Omega} \text{div}(\nabla \Delta u)\, dx \\
&= \int_{\Gamma} \underbrace{(\nabla \Delta u) \cdot n}_{= \ \partial_n \Delta u \ = \ 0 \text{ on } \Gamma} \, d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega} \underbrace{\nabla 1}_{= \ 0} \cdot (\nabla \Delta u) \, dx \\
&= 0
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \Delta f(u) \, dx &= \int_{\Omega} \text{div} (\nabla(f(u))  \,dx \\
&= \int_{\Gamma} \nabla f(u) \cdot n \, d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega} \underbrace{\nabla 1}_{= \ 0} \cdot \nabla f(u) \, dx \\
&= \int_{\Gamma} f'(u) \underbrace{(\nabla u \cdot n)}_{= \ \partial_{n} u \ = \ 0 \text{ on } \Gamma} \, d\Gamma \\
&= 0.
\end{align}